# How does Thor return to Asgard in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

If, after *Thor: The Dark World*,

> Loki is on the throne and Heimdall committed treason,

then how does Thor return to Asgard in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*?

Answer (score 14):

The last we saw, Loki was on the throne of Asgard - *disguised as Odin*. Since neither Thor or Sif have mentioned Odin's disappearance or Loki being in charge of Asgard since the events of *Thor: The Dark World* (both have appeared in either other movies or episodes of Agents of SHIELD), we can safely assume that Loki is still disguised as Odin.

Since Heimdall was still acting as the Gatekeeper of the Bifrost under Odin, despite having defied Loki when Loki was publicly in charge, removing him now would raise suspicions he is likely trying to avoid.

Additionally, as we see in the first *Thor*, Heimdall himself is not specifically required to be able to use the Bifrost, just his sword.

Comment: As for your last paragraph: Thor called Heimdall.

Comment: I'm referring to Heimdall leaving the sword in the control and walking away from the Bifrost to allow the warriors to go to Earth.

Comment: I am saying that the paragraph is irrelevant because Thor called Heimdall and only he could listen to that. So, it rules out the possibility that someone else operated the Bifrost.

Comment: I just rewatched the scene at the end of Age of Ultron. He does not call Heimdall or anyone else. He just raises Mjolnir and the Bifrost opens.

Comment: Wow. Looks like he got abducted.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So far, it hasn't been mentioned in the Canon how Heimdall was able to obey Thor to open the Bifrost in the Age of Ultron. And, in the next Thor movie, we'll surely get to know that.

Here are the possibilities:

- Loki is still waiting for the right time before he'd act to control the realm in his own favor. So, Heimdall is still the gatekeeper of the Asgard.
- It was Loki's trap to bring Thor to Asgard to imprison him or kill him or something else. After the events of *The Dark World*, Thor was presumably on Earth living with Jane. We don't know what happened on Asgard during this period. Maybe, Loki turned the Asgard into hell (Ragnarok). So, Loki was just waiting for the call from Thor.
- Odin took control over Asgard again and Loki was in prison at that point. This is less likely because MCU wants to take the story of Loki being King of Asgard forward, but this is one of the possibilities.

Comment: But in Thor the dark world it was heimdall who committed treason and surrendered himself to Odin now how has he returned? In the age of ultron deleted scenes thor was asked by Cap if "got any word from on high" i.e. did heimdall see anything. Thor's response was "Heimdall is either away from his post or been ordered not to answer." With that being said is that just a plot hole or could it mean something else?